# WebSphere portal server not starting

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-portal

I have a WebSphere portal server installed . Until now , it had been working properly . But due to some reason , I tried to clean restart it . But it is not starting now . Everytime I am getting the following stack trace ------

**me interface of the LicenseCheckStartup enterprise bean in the liccheckEJB.jar module of the LicenseCheck application.  The binding location is: java:global/LicenseCheck/liccheckEJB/LicenseCheckStartup!com.ibm.websphere.startupservice.AppStartUpHome
[11/6/17 16:58:36:243 IST] 00000062 SharedEJBRunt I   CWWSR0057I: EJB jar started: liccheckEJB.jar
[11/6/17 16:58:36:253 IST] 000000ad ServerCache   I   CWWDY1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named ws/com.ibm.wps.outbound.datastore.ProxyConfigCache.topologies initialized successfully.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:253 IST] 000000ad ServerCache   I   CWWDY1071I: The cache provider "default" is being used.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:253 IST] 000000ad ServerCache   I   CWWDY1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named ws/com.ibm.wps.outbound.datastore.ProxyConfigCache.values initialized successfully.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:253 IST] 000000ad ServerCache   I   CWWDY1071I: The cache provider "default" is being used.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:323 IST] 00000062 ServerCache   I   CWWDY1001I: WebSphere Dynamic Cache instance named ws/WSSecureMap initialized successfully.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:323 IST] 00000062 ServerCache   I   CWWDY1071I: The cache provider "default" is being used.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:363 IST] 00000062 SystemOut     O profileRoot from user.install.root =  G:\portal\wp_profile
[11/6/17 16:58:36:363 IST] 00000062 SystemOut     O [from wkplc.properties] _portalRoot = G:\portal\portal_server
[11/6/17 16:58:36:613 IST] 00000062 liccheck      E   CLFBD0026E: The product IBM WebSphere Portal Express does not have a valid license key installed and the evaluation period has expired. Functions specific to this product are not enabled.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:623 IST] 00000062 liccheck      E   CLFBD0030E: Caught error, message: Past the expiration date on license.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:623 IST] 00000062 AdminHelper   A   CWWMN1022I: An attempt is made to immediately stop the WebSphere_Portal server. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin)
[11/6/17 16:58:36:623 IST] 00000062 StartBeanInfo E   CWSTU0005E: Startup bean named ejb/com/ibm/wkplc/liccheck/AppStartUpHome forced application to stop.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:623 IST] 00000062 ApplicationMg W   CWWSR0101W: An error occurred starting, LicenseCheck
[11/6/17 16:58:36:633 IST] 00000062 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0217I: Stopping application: LicenseCheck
[11/6/17 16:58:36:653 IST] 00000062 SharedEJBRunt I   CWWSR0041I: Stopping EJB jar: liccheckEJB.jar
[11/6/17 16:58:36:684 IST] 00000062 SharedEJBRunt I   CWWSR0059I: EJB jar stopped: liccheckEJB.jar
[11/6/17 16:58:36:706 IST] 00000055 SchedulerServ I   CWSCH0034I: The Scheduler wps/Scheduler is stopping.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:712 IST] 00000055 SchedulerServ I   CWSCH0035I: The Scheduler wps/Scheduler has stopped.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:713 IST] 00000055 I18nService   I   CWWWI0010I: The Internationalization service is stopped on WebSphere_Portal.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:713 IST] 00000055 StartUpServic I   CWSTU0013I: The Startup Beans service has stopped.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:713 IST] 00000055 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0217I: Stopping application: PZN_Utilities
[11/6/17 16:58:36:727 IST] 00000055 ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper doDestroy CWSRV0253I: [PZN_Utilities] [/wps/pznutilities] [LMUtilityServlet]: Destroy successful.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:902 IST] 000000ad webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup CWSRV0169I: Loading Web Module: AJAX Proxy Configuration Service.
[11/6/17 16:58:36:903 IST] 00000062 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0220I: Application stopped: LicenseCheck
[11/6/17 16:58:36:938 IST] 000000ad WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext CWSEN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/wps/wp_proxy
[11/6/17 16:58:36:997 IST] 000000ad webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication CWSRV0250I: Web Module AJAX Proxy Configuration Service has been bound to default_host[*:10012,*:80,*:10014,*:10028,*:10029,*:443,*:10039,*:10042,*:10041].
[11/6/17 16:58:37:013 IST] 000000ad ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0221I: Application started: AJAX Proxy Configuration
[11/6/17 16:58:37:014 IST] 000000ad CompositionUn A   CWWSR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=AJAX Proxy Configuration in BLA WebSphere:blaname=AJAX Proxy Configuration started.
[11/6/17 16:58:37:016 IST] 000000ad CompositionUn A   CWWSR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=Seedlist_Servlet in BLA WebSphere:blaname=Seedlist_Servlet.
[11/6/17 16:58:37:040 IST] 00000062 CompositionUn E   CWWSR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=LicenseCheck in BLA WebSphere:blaname=LicenseCheck failed to start.
[11/6/17 16:58:37:068 IST] 000000ad ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0200I: Starting application: Seedlist_Servlet
[11/6/17 16:58:37:068 IST] 000000ad ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0204I: Application: Seedlist_Servlet  Application build level: Unknown
[11/6/17 16:58:37:133 IST] 00000055 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0220I: Application stopped: PZN_Utilities
[11/6/17 16:58:37:134 IST] 00000055 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0217I: Stopping application: PSESearchAdapter
[11/6/17 16:58:37:137 IST] 00000055 SharedEJBRunt I   CWWSR0041I: Stopping EJB jar: PSESearchAdapterEJB.jar
[11/6/17 16:58:37:154 IST] 00000055 SharedEJBRunt I   CWWSR0059I: EJB jar stopped: PSESearchAdapterEJB.jar
[11/6/17 16:58:37:231 IST] 00000055 ApplicationMg A   CWWSR0220I: Application stopped: PSESearchAdapter**

Because of this , my portal server is not starting . Can anybody help me out with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is pretty explicit why it is not starting

[11/6/17 16:58:36:613 IST] 00000062 liccheck E CLFBD0026E: The product IBM WebSphere Portal Express does not have a valid license key installed and the evaluation period has expired. Functions specific to this product are not enabled. 
[11/6/17 16:58:36:623 IST] 00000062 liccheck E CLFBD0030E: Caught error, message: Past the expiration date on license.

Is this a trial version you installed? I am not going to explicitly tell you how to bypass the trial license but did you some how delete your license file?

Comment: This is a trail version of WebSphere portal express . I did not change or remove any of the license files . But is there any way to extend the license period ? I am asking this because I have a lot of stuff configured in my portal server and everything would be deleted if I have to reinstall it .

Comment: google the error code and you should be able to find a way to work around it